ggcuminc function can not find
I am trying to calculate non-related mortality using competing risks using {tidycmprsk}.
Wen I try to plot my results with tidycmprsk::ggcuminc(), I am getting the information that ggcuminc() is not included in {tidycmprsk}.
Using the older version of {tidycmprsk} is not possible. With {ggsurvfit} the curves are not smooth enough.
Could you give me some advice?
cif_result <- tidycmprsk::cuminc(
  formula = Surv(OS_y, as.factor(Mortality)) ~ ALK_Status,
  data = Arbeitsversion_28_10)

tidycmprsk::ggcuminc(cif_result) +
  labs(x = "Years after alloSCT", y = "NRM") +
  theme_minimal()


Have you read https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/ggsurvfit/reference/ggcuminc.html? Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example You are very unlikely to receive an answer if you do not adapt to the given recommendations.
